# ViewScoped Constructor being called before save method in JSF 2.1.16

Tags: java, jsf-2, mojarra

Related to my JSF application, I noticed there's a problem with the **Mojarra JSF 2.1.16** library. I have a `ViewScoped` bean which loads a user from a login got as ViewParam. After that loaded user data can be managed and saved. Below is the view code, where I have skiped the main form fields as I have tested there's no problem with them.

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
template="/templates/general_template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam id="user" name="user"
            value="#{manager._ParamUser}" />
        <f:event type="preRenderView"
            listener="#{manager.initialize}" />
    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="general_content">
    <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="false" id="loggedData" name="loggedData"
        layout="block">
        <h:form id="SystemUserForm">

            <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellspacing="10px" style="border-color:red;">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.LOGIN}:" />
                <h:outputText value="#{manager._UserBean._login}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton value="#{msg.UPDATE}" action="#{manager.actionSave}"
    ajax="false" />

            <p:commandButton value="#{msg.CANCEL}"
    action="#{manager.actionCancelSave}" ajax="false" />
        </h:form>
    </p:outputPanel>
</ui:define>
```

At the beginning bean is created and User itself is loaded from data base using received param. Problem comes when I call the action method to save it, because the `ViewScoped` bean called `manager` is being constructed again. So there's no param and I have a **null pointer Exception**. That's working properly with **Mojarra 2.1.14** and **2.1.15**.

Backing bean code:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Manager extends UserData {

public static final String PARAM_USER = "ParamUser";

private String _ParamUser;

public String get_ParamUser() {
    return this._ParamUser;
}

public void set_ParamUser(String _ParamUser) {
    this._ParamUser = _ParamUser;
}

public Manager() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void initialize(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
        loadUserBean(this._ParamUser);
        if (this._UserBean == null) {
            redirectTo404();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public String actionSave() {
    super.actionSave();
    return NavigationResults.USER_LIST;
}
```

`UserData` is, of course, an abstract class. When `actionSave()` is called bean is constructed again and there is no `_ParamUser` attribute, because this is get by **viewParam**. That constructor recall is only happening with Mojarra 2.1.6.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. Please provide an SSCCE.

Comment: Edited. I try to be as clear as possible.

Comment: Provided that `/templates/general_template.xhtml` contains no bean references, I still don't see the problem. Note that the `#{manager}` isn't constructed at all while requesting the page because it's nowhere referenced by some output component or event. So it's only constructed when submitting the form. Perhaps this has confused you?

Comment: Wait, your `Manager` class has a `NavigableUserData` constructor? Did you post the real code? Or at least copypasted tested code?

Comment: Sorry, I changed some names for better understanding..

Comment: And the first point you've said, in fact `#{manager}` is called before, but I have skipped form field code because it was too long. I put you a short example about that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22400/discussion-between-xtreme-biker-and-balusc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved in Mojarra **JSF 2.1.17**, tried and tested. Could be a problem with **Mojarra JSF 2.1.16** and **Tomcat 6**. However, I haven't found any [known issues](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.1.16/issues.html) for that version.